# Is my memory use on Heroku too high? (RoR, Puma, Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I am getting an application set up on Heroku for production and have a hunch that my app's memory profile is quite big.  I'm looking for a gut-check / benchmarks to understand whether my app is 'bloated' or not optimized for performance.  I'm currently running 1 web dyno on Heroku with HireFire spinning up workers as needed for background tasks.

Current configuration:

puma.rb:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)  #
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Other relevant info:
 - Using a CDN for assets
 - Non-production gems are placed in development or test groups
 - No caching set up (yet)
 - Hobby basic DB
 - Stack: cedar-14

Current Status / Performance Data:

PumaAutoTune Gem:

```
PumaAutoTune (33445s): All is well puma.resource_ram_mb=500.58154296875     
puma.current_cluster_size=2  
source=web.1 dyno=heroku.xxxx
sample#load_avg_1m=0.31 sample#load_avg_5m=0.14 sample#load_avg_15m=0.12  
sample#memory_total=411.41MB sample#memory_rss=402.52MB   
sample#memory_cache=5.36MB sample#memory_swap=3.54MB 
sample#memory_pgpgin=1189542pages sample#memory_pgpgout=1085125pages
```

New Relic shows the following: 
[image: NewRelic instances]

Blitz test results:
[image: Blitz test results]

I have noticed that there's a difference in # of instances reported by PumaAutoTune for cluster size vs # of instances reported by New Relic.  I'm not sure if both terms refer to the same idea.

Switching to a VPS is on the table but I'm expecting a significant learning curve there as I'm self-taught and quite a novice at this, so it's not an ideal short-term solution.

Comment: Hi @UserDuser, did you manage to make your rails app work well on Heroku? What version of rails are you using?